# Elastic(search): Get docs with max and min timestamp values

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I got a problem with a search I just can't figure out how to do it. My docs are of the following form:

```json
{
"timestamp":"2015-03-17T15:05:04.563Z",
"session_id":"1",
"user_id":"jan"
}
```

Let's say the first timestamp of a session id is the "Login" and the last timestamp is the "Logout". I want to have all "login" and "logout" docs for all sessions (if possible sorted by `user_id`). I managed to get the right timestamps with aggregations:

```json
{
"aggs" : {
    "group_by_uid" : {
        "terms" : { 
            "field" : "user_id"
        },
        "aggs" : {
            "group_by_sid" : {
                "terms" : {
                    "field" : "session_id"
                },
                "aggs" : {
                    "max_date" : {
                        "max": { "field" : "timestamp" }
                    },
                    "min_date" : {
                        "min": { "field" : "timestamp" }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

But how do I get the corresponding docs? I also don't mind if i have to do 2 searches (one for the logins and one for the logouts). I tried tome top hits aggregations and sorting stuff but I always get parse errors :/

I hope someone can give me a hint :)

Best regards,
Jan

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's a solution in a single search based on the approach proposed by Sloan Ahrens. The advantage is that the start and end session entries are in the same bucket.

```json
{
"aggs": {
  "group_by_uid": {
     "terms": {
        "field": "user_id"
     },
     "aggs": {
        "group_by_sid": {
           "terms": {
              "field": "session_id"
           },
           "aggs": {
              "session_start": {
                 "top_hits": {
                    "size": 1,
                    "sort": [ { "timestamp": { "order": "asc" } } ]
                 }
              },
              "session_end": {
                 "top_hits": {
                    "size": 1,
                    "sort": [ { "timestamp": { "order": "desc" } } ]
                 }
              }
           }
        }
     }
  }
}
}
```

Cheers,
Jan

Answer (score 5):

You're already close. How about this. Use two searches, each aggregating the way you did, but then also get the first `top_hit` sorting on `"timestamp"`.

I just set up a basic index and added some data that looks like what you posted:

```
PUT /test_index
{
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 1
    }
}

POST /test_index/_bulk
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc","_id":1}}
{"timestamp":"2015-03-17T15:05:04.563Z","session_id":"1","user_id":"jan"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc","_id":2}}
{"timestamp":"2015-03-17T15:10:04.563Z","session_id":"1","user_id":"jan"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc","_id":3}}
{"timestamp":"2015-03-17T15:15:04.563Z","session_id":"1","user_id":"jan"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc","_id":4}}
{"timestamp":"2015-03-17T18:05:04.563Z","session_id":"1","user_id":"bob"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc","_id":5}}
{"timestamp":"2015-03-17T18:10:04.563Z","session_id":"1","user_id":"bob"}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc","_id":6}}
{"timestamp":"2015-03-17T18:15:04.563Z","session_id":"1","user_id":"bob"}
```

Then I can get each session's start time with:

```
POST /test_index/_search?search_type=count
{
   "aggs": {
      "group_by_uid": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "user_id"
         },
         "aggs": {
            "group_by_sid": {
               "terms": {
                  "field": "session_id"
               },
               "aggs": {
                  "session_start": {
                     "top_hits": {
                        "size": 1,
                        "sort": [ { "timestamp": { "order": "asc" } } ]
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 5,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 6,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "group_by_uid": {
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "bob",
               "doc_count": 3,
               "group_by_sid": {
                  "buckets": [
                     {
                        "key": "1",
                        "doc_count": 3,
                        "session_start": {
                           "hits": {
                              "total": 3,
                              "max_score": null,
                              "hits": [
                                 {
                                    "_index": "test_index",
                                    "_type": "doc",
                                    "_id": "4",
                                    "_score": null,
                                    "_source": {
                                       "timestamp": "2015-03-17T18:05:04.563Z",
                                       "session_id": "1",
                                       "user_id": "bob"
                                    },
                                    "sort": [
                                       1426615504563
                                    ]
                                 }
                              ]
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "jan",
               "doc_count": 3,
               "group_by_sid": {
                  "buckets": [
                     {
                        "key": "1",
                        "doc_count": 3,
                        "session_start": {
                           "hits": {
                              "total": 3,
                              "max_score": null,
                              "hits": [
                                 {
                                    "_index": "test_index",
                                    "_type": "doc",
                                    "_id": "1",
                                    "_score": null,
                                    "_source": {
                                       "timestamp": "2015-03-17T15:05:04.563Z",
                                       "session_id": "1",
                                       "user_id": "jan"
                                    },
                                    "sort": [
                                       1426604704563
                                    ]
                                 }
                              ]
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

and end-time with:

```
POST /test_index/_search?search_type=count
{
   "aggs": {
      "group_by_uid": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "user_id"
         },
         "aggs": {
            "group_by_sid": {
               "terms": {
                  "field": "session_id"
               },
               "aggs": {
                  "session_end": {
                     "top_hits": {
                        "size": 1,
                        "sort": [ { "timestamp": { "order": "desc" } } ]
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 6,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "group_by_uid": {
         "buckets": [
            {
               "key": "bob",
               "doc_count": 3,
               "group_by_sid": {
                  "buckets": [
                     {
                        "key": "1",
                        "doc_count": 3,
                        "session_end": {
                           "hits": {
                              "total": 3,
                              "max_score": null,
                              "hits": [
                                 {
                                    "_index": "test_index",
                                    "_type": "doc",
                                    "_id": "6",
                                    "_score": null,
                                    "_source": {
                                       "timestamp": "2015-03-17T18:15:04.563Z",
                                       "session_id": "1",
                                       "user_id": "bob"
                                    },
                                    "sort": [
                                       1426616104563
                                    ]
                                 }
                              ]
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "key": "jan",
               "doc_count": 3,
               "group_by_sid": {
                  "buckets": [
                     {
                        "key": "1",
                        "doc_count": 3,
                        "session_end": {
                           "hits": {
                              "total": 3,
                              "max_score": null,
                              "hits": [
                                 {
                                    "_index": "test_index",
                                    "_type": "doc",
                                    "_id": "3",
                                    "_score": null,
                                    "_source": {
                                       "timestamp": "2015-03-17T15:15:04.563Z",
                                       "session_id": "1",
                                       "user_id": "jan"
                                    },
                                    "sort": [
                                       1426605304563
                                    ]
                                 }
                              ]
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Here's the code I used:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/05edb48b840e6a992646643913db8ef0a3ccccb3

Comment: Thank you very much. I could swear I tried the same but appearently I had something wrong. Also thank you for the Qbox.io link. This looks useful for testing as I am using the java API :) I cannot upvote your answer yet...

Comment: I just got anotther question: are the result always ordered the same for session start and end? i.e. if I want to merge the search hits together, correspond the first session start search hit always to the first session end search hit?